# How to call the default X509KeyManager when creating a wrapper around a X509KeyManager

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp, x509, pki

I am trying to implement a wrapper around a `X509KeyManager` to execute other code inside the callbacks and then call the the default KeyManager after but this isn't working.

Here's my simplified code:

```
class MyKeyManager(): X509ExtendedKeyManager() {
  private val defaultKeyManager: X509ExtendedKeyManager

  init {
    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())

    keyManagerFactory.init(null, null)
    val keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.keyManagers
    check(keyManagers.size == 1 && keyManagers[0] is X509ExtendedKeyManager) {
      "Error Creating KeyManager"
    }
    defaultKeyManager = keyManagers[0] as X509ExtendedKeyManager
  }

  override fun getClientAliases(keyType: String?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?): Array<String> {
    return defaultKeyManager.getClientAliases(keyType, issuers)
  }

  override fun chooseClientAlias(keyType: Array<out String>?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?, socket: Socket?): String {
// execute code
    return defaultKeyManager.chooseClientAlias(keyType, issuers, socket)
  }

  override fun getServerAliases(keyType: String?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?): Array<String> {
    return defaultKeyManager.getServerAliases(keyType, issuers)
  }

  override fun chooseServerAlias(keyType: String?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?, socket: Socket?): String {
    return defaultKeyManager.chooseServerAlias(keyType, issuers, socket)
  }

  override fun getCertificateChain(alias: String?): Array<X509Certificate> {
// execute code
    return defaultKeyManager.getCertificateChain(alias)
  }

  override fun getPrivateKey(alias: String?): PrivateKey {
// execute code
    return defaultKeyManager.getPrivateKey(alias)
  }

  override fun chooseEngineClientAlias(keyType: Array<out String>?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?, engine: SSLEngine?): String {
    return defaultKeyManager.chooseEngineClientAlias(keyType, issuers, engine)
  }

  override fun chooseEngineServerAlias(keyType: String?, issuers: Array<out Principal>?, engine: SSLEngine?): String {
    return defaultKeyManager.chooseEngineServerAlias(keyType, issuers, engine)
  }
}
```

and when I run my app I get this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.mytestapp1, PID: 20624
    java.lang.Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: defaultKeyManager.choose…keyType, issuers, socket) must not be null
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: defaultKeyManager.choose…keyType, issuers, socket) must not be null
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:363)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:285)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.access$1000(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:54)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.renegotiate(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:929)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:884)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readUntilDataAvailable(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:824)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:797)
...
```

I am using OkHttp to run this code and I create my Client like this:

```
      val keyManager = MyKeyManager()
      sslContext.init(arrayOf<X509KeyManager>(keyManager), TrustAllTrusManager, null)
      val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder().protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
        .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.socketFactory, TrustAllTrusManager[0])
```

Does anyone anyone know if this is the correct way of creating the default X509KeyManager or why this exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the exception was thrown because the methods overwritten from `x509ExtendedKeyManager` needed to be marked as nullable.
All of these methods in the java interface can return `null` and I wasn't making them nullable when implementing them in Kotlin